# Why "click_no_wait" is slower than "click"?

Tags: watir

After I click a button with "click_no_wait" method, there is a delay of almost one second before anything happens... Why is this so?

Here is one example (obvious delay between button's yellow-flash and popup window):

```
require 'watir'
b = Watir::Browser.start "www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_alert"
b.frame(:name, "view").button(:text, "Show alert box").click_no_wait
```

If I replace "click_no_wait" with just "click", then there is not any delay after clicking a button (popup window shows up instantly). But "click" can't be used here because then the script hangs...

Is there any solution for this delay? (Not a big problem really, just asking...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It launches a separate process.

The plus side is that it prevents hanging because the main process can get on with things immediately. The down side is that setting up a process takes time in itself.

It's a balancing found in anything in any language that uses separate processes or separate threads - increased responsiveness and increased performance in certain cases, but with an overhead in and of itself.

You might find http://itreallymatters.net/post/1366392123/debugging-and-improving-watirs-click-no-wait-method of interest.